# How to find the most influential paths in a weighted, directed graph

Tags: graphs-and-networks, code-request

Given a weighted, directed graph, I want to find the most influential paths (a combination of large weights). I reverse the usual shortest path problem because the context I am trying to model defines the shortest paths as paths with the largest influence weights. This means that the input into the usual shortest path algorithm should be the reciprocal of the weighted, directed graph. However, if I take the reciprocal of the weighted graph below, `Infinity` creates a problem, and I do not know how to handle this case.

I refer to the following weighted, directed graph for this problem.

```
WeightedAdjacencyGraph[{{\[Infinity], \[Infinity], 2, 
   1.4`}, {1.6`, \[Infinity], 
   1.9`, \[Infinity]}, {2, \[Infinity], \[Infinity], 
   0.62`}, {\[Infinity], \[Infinity], \[Infinity], \[Infinity]}}, 
 DirectedEdges -> True, VertexLabels -> "Name"]
HighlightGraph[%, PathGraph@FindShortestPath[%, 2, 4]]
```

What will be the longest path(s) between vertices 2 and 4 through an edge, say, from  vertex 2 to 1?

Comment: Could you just replace $\infty$ with a large finite number instead? like `wadj = (*weighted adj. mat.*)/.Infinity->10^6`?

Comment: What is "the reciprocal of a graph"? Are you sure that the longest path problem is a good fit for your application? The classic definition of longest paths forbids repeated vertices. Otherwise, you could make the path arbitrarily long by going around the cycle you have in this graph. But forbidding repeated vertices causes this to be NP-hard.

Comment: @Szabolcs: I used a wrong terminology. The reciprocal refers to (1/a) with a being a constant.

Comment: @ydd: If I replace large numbers, then those numbers will be used in `FindPath`, which I do not want. I want to exclude them from the analysis. I think @Daniel's code is the right way to go.

Comment: @ydd it does not return the longest path. The problem is that inverting the adjacency matrix inverts each edge weight individually, instead of inverting the full weight of the path. This can be a problem because $1/a_1+1/b_1$ < $1/a_1+1/b_2+1/c_2$ does not imply $a_1+b_1$ > $a_1+b_2+c_2$ (Ex: look at path length of `{2,1,3,4}` compared to this path `{2,1,4}`

Comment: @TugrulTemel sorry that I had to add another comment, but I just realized I @ myself instead of you in the above comment and it is too late to edit :(

Comment: @ydd: no problem. I understood it as a typo.

Comment: @Szabolcs: You raised a critical question about the suitability of a longest path search (in fact, it is the shortest in my formulation.). The reason for inverting the edge weights is precisely for escaping the problem you mentioned in your comment. If I formulated my question as a search for longest path without adjusting the edge weights first, you would be perfectly right. Therefore, I deliberately tried to represent the problem as the shortest path search after the division of edge weights to 1. I hope my argument makes sense!

Comment: @ydd: Maybe I misunderstood your point. I simply convert the original matrix to an inverted one and find the shortest path, which will give me the path with the min sum of the edge weights associated with the largest edge weights.

Comment: @TugrulTemel the shortest path with the inverted weights is not in general the longest path with the original weights. Take this example: Suppose you have two paths between two vertices, one that goes through one other vertex and one that goes through two. Suppose the original edge weights of these two paths are `{1/4,1/2}` and `{1/4,1/2,1/2}` for total path weights 3/4 and 5/4 (so the second is longer). Taking the inverse weights of these paths we have `{4,2}` and `{4,2,2}`, so `FindShortestPath` will return the first path, even though it's shorter than the second in the original graph.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/147745/discussion-between-ydd-and-tugrul-temel).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea to take the inverse weight and search the shortest path is good. You simply need to retain the infinite weights:

```
dat1 = {{∞, ∞, 2, 1.4`}, {1.6`, ∞, 
    1.9`, ∞}, {2, ∞, ∞, 
    0.62`}, {∞, ∞, ∞, ∞}};
dat2 = Map[(If[# == ∞, ∞, 1/#]) &, dat1, {2}]
```

We now create the original graph for display and the graph with inverse weight for the shortest path:

```
gr1 = WeightedAdjacencyGraph[dat1, DirectedEdges -> True, 
  VertexLabels -> "Name", EdgeLabels -> "EdgeWeight"];
gr2 = WeightedAdjacencyGraph[dat2, DirectedEdges -> True, 
  VertexLabels -> "Name", EdgeLabels -> "EdgeWeight"];
```

Finally we display the longest path in the original graph:

```
HighlightGraph[gr1, PathGraph@FindShortestPath[gr2, 2, 4]]
```

[image]

Comment: Is there any way to count the number of paths that includes a given edge? I did the following and it works but I suspect an easier way exist. `lstPaths = FindPath[gr2, 2,4, Infinity, All];
edges = DirectedEdge @@@ Partition[#, 2, 1] & /@ lstPaths;
propSP = 
 Count[Flatten@edges, "1" \[DirectedEdge] "3"]/Length[edges] // N`

Comment: In graphs with circular paths like your example, there are infinite many paths through some edge.

Answer (score 4):

I suppose one inefficient way could be to calculate all the possible paths from vertex 2 to 4, and then select the one with the highest path weight. This will get very slow for graphs with more edges.

```
originalAdj = 
 {{\[Infinity], \[Infinity], 2, 1.4`}, {1.6`, \[Infinity], 
    1.9`, \[Infinity]}, {2, \[Infinity], \[Infinity], 
    0.62`}, {\[Infinity], \[Infinity], \[Infinity], \[Infinity]}};
g = WeightedAdjacencyGraph[originalAdj, DirectedEdges -> True, 
  VertexLabels -> "Name"]
```

Then I calculate all possible paths from 2 to 4 using `FindPath`:

```
paths = FindPath[g, 2, 4, Infinity, All]
(*{{2, 3, 4}, {2, 1, 4}, {2, 3, 1, 4}, {2, 1, 3, 4}}*)
```

I am not sure if a built in function exists for calculating path length of a given path, so I just made this myself. It just adds up the edge weights along the path:

```
calcPathWeight[pathIn_] := 
 Sum[Part[originalAdj, i /. List -> Sequence], {i, 
   Partition[pathIn, 2, 1]}]
```

And then find the path with the largest total weight:

```
longestPath=Flatten@paths[[PositionLargest[calcPathWeight /@ paths]]]
(*{2, 3, 1, 4}*)
```

We can make the highlighted graph by converting the list of vertices visited to a list of rules:

```
longPathRuleList = 
 Table[longestPath[[i - 1]] -> longestPath[[i]], {i, 2, 
   Length@longestPath}];

HighlightGraph[g, PathGraph@longPathRuleList]
```

[image]

Edit: Apologies for having to edit so many times, but I did not see you also wanted the longest path that *also* goes through the vertex 2->1. We can do this by filtering out only the paths that have this vertex:

```
edges = Partition[#, 2, 1] & /@ paths;
truePos = Flatten[Position[MemberQ[#, {2, 1}] & /@ edges, True]];
pathsCandidates = paths[[truePos]]
(*{{2, 1, 4}, {2, 1, 3, 4}}*)
```

And then use the same method as above for finding the longest path in `pathsCandidates`.